# I need to send and receive UDP packets from Teensy

Tags: tcp, udp, udpclient, teensy

I have a communication diagram like

[image]

In this project, there is a udp communication between python code in linux os and teensy.Different sensors connected to teensy and teensy send the sensor datas to linux with udp.

I must send udp request to teensy to get sensor datas.

The person who wrote the code to run on Teensy wrote such a line for request and receive operations. Then there is information about the parameters.
E.g;

Request

```
Start_Packet/Size_of_Packet/Communication_Type/Message_ID/Message/CRC16/End_Packet
```

Response

```
Start_Packet/Size_of_Packet/Communication_Type/Message_ID/Message/CRC16/End_Packet
```

**Start_Packet:** $

**Size_of_Packet:**
Only message bytes length.

**Communication_Types:**

UNKNOWN_COMMUNICATION 0

CAN0 1

..

**Message_ID:**
Packet number. Max: 100
if not response data message id = 0xFF

**Message:**
Data to be send. Max: 18 bytes

**CRC16:**
Before the CRC16 bytes will be calculated.
CRC16_CCIT_ZERO
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

**End_Packet:** #

I can not understand this request response lines. For example in python client, I sent the data as a string and server received. But in there, how should be request ?

Comment: I'm sorry it's really not clear what you are asking here. Edit the question to add more details and explain what you've tried

Comment: @hardillb Thank you for the answer. I tried to fix the question. I hope it was clearer. I do not know what will I do. I only need to send udp request and receive udp data, but I could not understand the format of the data to be sent.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see enough information here to help from a Node-RED perspective

Comment: Actually, in node-red there will be udp request and response. The coder said that request will be like ```Start_Packet/Size_of_Packet/Communication_Type/Message_ID/Message/CRC16/End_Packet``` and I don't understand this format

Comment: @hardillb , normal udp request or response can be string for example. But, what is this ? There are many /, should I use these ?

Comment: We can't help you with that, the only person that can is the person that created that code.

Comment: @hardillb thank you